# button and textview dont show on android studio basic layout

Tags: java, android-studio

when I open android studio in basic layout mode it doesn't show the next button and the textview. It was working when I installed it but then suddenly stopped. It first shows an exclamation mark(for error) in front of nav_host_fragment which i fix using the suggested fix provided by android studio but then everything goes away. I am new to android studio so I'm not sure if I'm missing anything.

[image]

Comment: Which `Button` and `TextView` are you referring to? Are they possibly in `fragment_first` or `fragment_second`, rather than `content_main`?

Comment: @Mike M. yes I'm referring to the default Button and TextView which appear with the basic layout. i.e fragment_first and Button1

Comment: Well, you have `content_main` open, not `fragment_first`. Look in the left-hand panel.

Comment: @MikeM. check out my component tree it doesnt show the next button or the first fragment textview.

Comment: @MikeM. Oh OK it doesn't show up on all pages. Thanks a lot. Also why don't u send it as an answer. I won't be able to accept it otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it's normal because there is no Views on your `content_main.xml`

try to open `fragment_first.xml` and check it